# c++ The evaluation of expression. How to exit the while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, stack, expression

I use stack to evaluate an expression.
The most important function is below:

```
double Expression_Eval() 
{ 
SeqStack<char,100> OPTR;                
SeqStack<double,100> OPND;      
OPTR.Push('@');
char ch;
ch=getchar();   
while (ch!='@' || OPTR.GetTop()!='@')
{  
    if (!InOPTR(ch))        
    {  
        int n=ch-'0';
        double num=(double)n;
        OPND.Push(num); 
        ch=getchar();   
    }       
    else                        
    { 
        char pre_op=OPTR.GetTop();
        switch (Precede(pre_op, ch))
        { 
            case '<': OPTR.Push(ch);                          
                      ch=getchar();                         
                      break;
            case '=': OPTR.Pop(); 
                      ch=getchar();                       
                      break;
            case '>': double b=OPND.Pop();  
                      double a=OPND.Pop();   
                      pre_op=OPTR.Pop();
                      OPND.Push(Operate(a, pre_op, b));
                      ch=getchar();                        
                      break;
        }
    }
}
return OPND.GetTop(); 
}
```

Then, when I input *8/(5-3)@*, it will not print the result.

I think the loop termination condition **ch!='@' || OPTR.GetTop()!='@'** is wrong.
When I press *Enter*, getchar() get the last char is **CR** but not **@**.

But, I don't know how to revise it to make my program work.

The other part of my program is below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename DataType,int StackSize>
class SeqStack
{
private:
DataType data[StackSize];
int top;
public:
SeqStack()
{   top=-1;     }
~SeqStack() {}
void Push(DataType x)
{
    if(top == StackSize-1)
        throw "error";
    data[++top]=x;
}
DataType Pop()
{
    if(top == -1)
        throw "error";
    DataType x=data[top--];
    return x;
}
DataType GetTop()
{
    if(top != -1)
        return data[top];
    else
        cout<<"error";
}
};
bool InOPTR(char ch)
{
if( (ch>='(' && ch<='+') || ch=='-' || ch=='/' )
{
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
char Precede(char op1, char op2)
{
char pri[7][7]={ {'>','>','<','<','<','>','>'}
                , {'>','>','<','<','<','>','>'}
                , {'>','>','>','>','<','>','>'}
                , {'>','>','>','>','<','>','>'}
                , {'<','<','<','<','<','=','@'}
                , {'>','>','>','>','@','>','>'}
                , {'<','<','<','<','<','@','='} };
int m,n;
switch(op1)
{
case '+': m=0;break;
case '-': m=1;break;
case '*': m=2;break;
case '/': m=3;break;
case '(': m=4;break;
case ')': m=5;break;
case '@': m=6;break;
}
switch(op2)
{
case '+': n=0;break;
case '-': n=1;break;
case '*': n=2;break;
case '/': n=3;break;
case '(': n=4;break;
case ')': n=5;break;
case '@': n=6;break;
}
return pri[m][n];
}
double Operate(double a, char op, double b)
{
double result;
switch(op)
{
case '+': result=a+b; break;
case '-': result=a-b; break;
case '*': result=a*b; break;
case '/': result=a/b; break;
}
return result;
}    
int main()
{
   double r=Expression_Eval();
   cout<<r<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem seem to be that '@' is considered a number, but it should be considered an operation:

Use:

```
bool InOPTR(char ch) {
    if ((ch >= '(' && ch <= '+') || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch=='@'){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that '@' is ASCII 64 which is not covered in the ranage '(' to '+' [40-43]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Actually, I found this mistake by debuging on my own. Thank you for reading my code and helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume carriage return or newline character after `getchar();` which comes into play when you press enter button.

One trick is as below.

```
ch=getchar(); 

getchar(); //this getchar to consume CR.
```

since you have used `ch = getchar()` many times you have to use above solution at many places.

Better solution to this problem will be to `enter string` instead of entering single character using `getchar()`...

Hope you got what I am trying to say...

Comment: Yes, I got your thought. Actually, I want to enter string instead of entering single character at first. But my teacher give the Expression_Eval() and I just based on it. Could you find out where I should put the getchar()? I tried some times just now but failed.

Comment: instead of putting `ch=getchar()` at so many places you should put (only once) `ch=getchar(); getchar()` after `else` statement result will be same... give it a try...